# How do I convert from int to Long in Java?

Tags: java, casting, int, long-integer

I keep finding both on here and Google people having troubles going from `long` to `int` and not the other way around. Yet I'm sure I'm not the only one that has run into this scenario before going from `int` to `Long`.

The only other answers I've found were "Just set it as Long in the first place" which really doesn't address the question.

I initially tried casting but I get a "`Cannot cast from int to Long`"

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); ++i ) {
    content = new Content();
    content.setDescription(myArrayList.get(i));
    content.setSequence((Long) i);
    session.save(content);
}
```

As you can imagine I'm a little perplexed, I'm stuck using `int` since some content is coming in as an `ArrayList` and the entity for which I'm storing this info requires the sequence number as a Long.

Comment: for (long i = 0; i < myList.size(); ++i) works too

Comment: @Instantsoup Yes that will work for the loop, but as I specified at the bottom of my question the ArrayList I'm working with requires the primitive int when specifying what index position to get

Comment: long longValue = intValue | 0L;

Comment: What I did is: cast `int` to `long` first, then assign `long` to `Long`. e.g `int x = 2; Long y = (long)x;`

Answer (score 265, accepted):

Note that there is a difference between a cast to `long` and a cast to `Long`. If you cast to `long` (a primitive value) then it should be automatically boxed to a `Long` (the reference type that wraps it).

You could alternatively use `new` to create an instance of `Long`, initializing it with the `int` value.

Comment: To demonstrate what Earwicker said you could call Long.valueOf(i), which takes a long but will widen an int and give you back a Long object.

Comment: Autoboxing is preferable, because it doesn't necessarily have to create a new `Long` object every time.

Comment: (Warning: the rest of this comment is guesswork and conjecture)

If the values given to Long.valueOf() fall between 0 and 128, which is very common, and it returns a cached instance, will that be preferable over autoboxing? (I may ask a new question if you think it's worth it...)

Comment: Autoboxing does the same thing as that. By the way, it's between -127 and 128.

Comment: @Grundlefleck: Autoboxing uses `Long.valueOf()` (if I remember correctly), so there wouldn't be a difference at all. My comment was in reply to the answer, not to your comment.

Comment: And watch out for accidentally writing `a == b` to compare two boxed values! Will appear to work if they're in the "interning" range, will fail if not. And the range is a *minimum* of -128 to 127, but may be larger. (I think that's right, looks like I typed it the wrong way round in my last comment).

Comment: @mmyers: ah I see, cheers.

@Earwicker: may I be so bold to suggest there's some information in these comments that would earn your answer at least another +1 were it to be included? :-)

Comment: @Grundlefleck - thanks, but would probably make more sense on a question about what autoboxing is equivalent to, e.g. you could upvote this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766468/autoboxing-so-i-can-write-integer-i-0-instead-of-integer-i-new-integer0/767167#767167

Answer (score 229):

Use the following: [`Long.valueOf(int);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf%28long%29).

Comment: Look out, as this will generate a NullPointerException if you are receiving a Integer object which is null.

Comment: correct if am wron i thought may be the answer is old becuse i cant find the method `Long.valueOf(int) !!`

Comment: @will824 - a primitive 'int' variable cannot be null.

Comment: @shareef - see serg's comment - but I think this method casts the int to a long which autoboxes with a Long... so seems redundant

Comment: @Rondo an `Integer` can, which is what he said.

Comment: @1blustone either way, it is a red herring: if an Integer was received then a nullpointer would not be generated by this call but by the attempt to get the number into the required primitive: long (Long.valueOf(int) doesn't exists)

Comment: There is no such method in Java, you mistook it for `Long.valueOf(long)`

Answer (score 26):

If you already have the int typed as an Integer you can do this:

```
Integer y = 1;
long x = y.longValue();
```

Answer (score 20):

use

```
new Long(your_integer);
```

or

```
Long.valueOf(your_integer);
```

Answer (score 11):

```
 1,new Long(intValue);
 2,Long.valueOf(intValue);
```

Comment: For anyone trying now, Long.valueOf(intValue) is the way to go and constructor approach is deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

How About

```
int myInt = 88;
```

// Will not compile

```
Long myLong = myInt;
```

// Compiles, and retains the non-NULL spirit of int. The best *cast* is *no cast at all*.  Of course, your use case may require Long and possible NULL values.  But if the int, or other longs are your only input, and your method can be modified, I would suggest this approach.

```
long myLong = myInt;
```

// Compiles, is the most efficient way, and makes it clear that the source value, is and will never be NULL.

```
Long myLong = (long) myInt;
```

Answer (score 7):

In Java you can do:

```
 int myInt=4;
 Long myLong= new Long(myInt);
```

in your case it would be:

```
content.setSequence(new Long(i));
```

Answer (score 6):

I have this little toy, that also deals with non generic interfaces.
I'm OK with it throwing a ClassCastException if feed wrong (OK and happy)

```
public class TypeUtil {
    public static long castToLong(Object o) {
        Number n = (Number) o;
        return n.longValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We shall get the long value by using `Number` reference.

```
public static long toLong(Number number){
    return number.longValue();
}
```

It works for all number types, here is a test:

```
public static void testToLong() throws Exception {
    assertEquals(0l, toLong(0));   // an int
    assertEquals(0l, toLong((short)0)); // a short
    assertEquals(0l, toLong(0l)); // a long
    assertEquals(0l, toLong((long) 0)); // another long
    assertEquals(0l, toLong(0.0f));  // a float
    assertEquals(0l, toLong(0.0));  // a double

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a great deal of trouble with this. I just wanted to:

```
thisBill.IntervalCount = jPaidCountSpinner.getValue();
```

Where IntervalCount is a Long, and the JSpinner was set to return a Long.  Eventually I had to write this function:

```
    public static final Long getLong(Object obj) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    Long rv;

    if((obj.getClass() == Integer.class) || (obj.getClass() == Long.class) || (obj.getClass() == Double.class)) {
        rv = Long.parseLong(obj.toString());
    }
    else if((obj.getClass() == int.class) || (obj.getClass() == long.class) || (obj.getClass() == double.class)) {
        rv = (Long) obj;
    }
    else if(obj.getClass() == String.class) {
        rv = Long.parseLong(obj.toString());
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("getLong: type " + obj.getClass() + " = \"" + obj.toString() + "\" unaccounted for");
    }

    return rv;
}
```

which seems to do the trick.  No amount of simple casting, none of the above solutions worked for me.  Very frustrating.

Comment: if `jPaidCountSpinner.getValue()` returns an Object that is in fact a `Long`, you definitely only need to put a `(Long)` cast in front. Also try putting a breakpoint on your check for `int.class` or `long.class` etc. Does it ever hit it? And if you have a number-like object, it will support `java.util.Number`, so cast it to that and call the `longValue` method. No need to go via a string in that case. So this function could be simplified quite a bit, even if you also need to deal with strings. (Part of the problem here is the bad reference documentation for `JSpinner`).

Comment: I too ended up doing something like this. I wasn't sure what kind of number I would receive and was willing to convert it to Long with little concern for efficiency but wanting to avoid boilerplate.

Answer (score 2):

```
 //Suppose you have int and you wan to convert it to Long
 int i=78;
 //convert to Long
 Long l=Long.valueOf(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggested From Android Studio lint check : Remove Unnecessary boxing : So, unboxing is :

```
public  static  long  integerToLong (int minute ){
    int delay = minute*1000;
    long diff = (long) delay;
    return  diff ; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other ways suggested here, one can try the below code as well.

```
(long)intValue
```

primitive to primitive.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as there is only method `Long.valueOf(long)`, cast from `int` to `long` will be done implicitly in case of using `Long.valueOf(intValue)`.

The more clear way to do this is

```
Integer.valueOf(intValue).longValue()
```

Comment: `longValue` is just a `(long)`, so the only thing you "gain" here is `Integer`'s internal cache.

Comment: yeah. how about just ``(long) intValue`` ?