# Why did JDK designers took the decision of not doing type conversion and then auto boxing?

Tags: java, long-integer

In Java, the following line does not give compilation error

```
long a = 10;
```

But the following line throws compilation error "Incompatible type"

```
Long a = 10;
```

I know the above statement should be written as

```
Long a = 10L;
```

But I would like to understand why did JDK designers took the decision of not doing type conversion and then auto boxing and only doing one of them?

Comment: 1. `10` is a integer number literal, and java treats that as `int`. 2. It's not failing because `int` can be implicitly upcast to `long`. 3. Autoboxing `10` would make an `Integer` because `10` is an `int`. 4. If Java were to autobox in your second line, then that would make it `Long a = Integer.valueOf(10)`, but there's a problem there: `Long` is not a supertype of `Integer`. And the language designers said **no** to 2 implicit conversions (first upcast to `long`, then autobox to `Long`)

Comment: I don't understand the negative votes. It's a legitimate question that only Java designers are qualified to answer. Maybe it was to keep the compiler fast and simple. Maybe it was to protect the coder from bugs. E.g. what should happen if you wrote Long a = 'a'?

Comment: In Scala you can do `val a: Long = 10` so it seems like a reasonable question to me. The question is about language design, not what is the actual syntax of Java.

Comment: @kai what a stupid comparison

Comment: @Simon that is again another story. Now that is about comparing languages. That indeed has an answer. Back in the days when Java was created they didn't want intergers as in c, that are overlapping and different on every os(implementation). They wanted to make a difference. It was at that time they pinned them to fixed sizes: 1L is something defined different than 1. Autoboxing came way later.   Now Scala again does a lot different especialy in regard to parsing...

Answer (score 1):

It's default behavior. To use a `Long` constant just add an "l" at the end of the number:

```
Long number = 10l;
```

Comment: I know that. I want to understand why java took that decision.

Comment: I prefer "L" because it is easier to read

Comment: @Sashwat that is simple because you wrote a sematically  wrong line. Java didn't "decide" anything but you wrote something that is simply wrong.

Comment: JDK could have done a type-conversion and then a auto-boxing. The question is Why did JDK designer took the decision of not doing it?

Comment: It can autobox primitives only to their correspondent type, like `long -> Long`, `int -> Integer` and so on. And while it *can* convert `int` to `long`, it *can't* convert `Integer` to `Long`

Comment: It's more a matter of logic than of design

Comment: @ayrton his questions is why it implicitly doesn't do `int -> long -> Long`, and not `int -> Integer -> Long`

Answer (score 0):

The first example doesn't give compilation error because `long` type is wider than `int`. You can do assignment like:

```
double -> float -> long -> int -> short -> byte
```

The second example requires autoboxing, but java can autobox primitive types to corresponding wrappers only. E.g. `long` to `Long`, `int` to `Integer`,...

That's why to distinguish different types you can add letter:

`5L` - long, `5d` - double, `5f`- float

See here for more details [Java: Why can't I cast int to Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765874/java-why-cant-i-cast-int-to-long)

Comment: doesn't answer the question