# Long.valueOf not compiling for converting int to long

Tags: java, int, long-integer

Looking at the answers to this question (link: [How do I convert from int to Long in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302605/how-do-i-convert-from-int-to-long-in-java)), I used the following to compare long values (newUpdate, lastUpdate) with int value (Interval)

`if ((newUpdate - lastUpdate) > Long.valueOf(interval))`

I am not able to compile. What is the correct way to compare two different types?

More Info:

`[INFO] Trace org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Compilation failure [145,51] operator > cannot be applied to long,java.lang.Long`

Interval is of the type `int`.

Comment: What is the compilation error? Is `Interval` of type `int` or `Integer`?

Comment: [INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Compilation failure
[145,51] operator > cannot be applied to long,java.lang.Long

Comment: Interval is of the type int.

Comment: I would kindly ask you to refrain from starting variable names with uppercase letters. Please find additional information in the [Java Code Conventions, Chapter 9: Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Thank you very much, you will help everyone reading your code not getting a myocardial infarction or developing suicidal tendencies. ;)

Comment: I changed the Interval to interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `interval` is an `int`, then just ...

```
    if ((newUpdate - lastUpdate) > interval) { ...
```

There is NO good reason to explicitly convert `interval` to a `long` in this context.  The conversion will be done for you anyway.

The expression `Long.valueOf(Interval)` returns a `java.lang.Long` rather than a `long`.  If you *needed* to explicitly turn `interval` into a `long`, then you should cast it:

```
    if ((newUpdate - lastUpdate) > ((long) interval)) {
```

---

<sup>The only thing that puzzles me about your example is why you get a compilation error when comparing a `long` and a `Long`.  The `Long` *should* be auto-unboxed and the `long`, `long` version of the `>` operator should be used: reference [JLS - 15.20.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1) which says that numeric relational operators perform unboxing if required. The only explanation can be that you are compiling with the source level at 1.4 or earlier.</sup>

Comment: Why? So there is no reason to convert an int to long?

Comment: @RedDopamine The `int` will automatically be casted to `long`.

Comment: Using just interval works. Long.valueOf(Interval).longValue() Yogendra's answer also works fine.

Comment: It's hard to remember to understand when there is a deadline

Answer (score 0):

`Long.valueOf(Interval)` retuns wrapper object `Long` hence `>` operator is not applicable.

If `Interval` is String type then use `Long.valueOf(Interval).longValue()` in your comparison.

If `Interval` is `int` type then just use `Interval` in your comparison. It will be auto promoted to `long` -->[specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#d5e6284).

Comment: I used Long.valueOf(Interval).longValue() and it works fine now. I will try only Interval too.

Comment: @RedDopamine - programming is not about trying different fixes until you find something that "works".  You need to understand the Java language so that you *know* what your original mistake was, and can choose the right fix.