# ArrayList storing other than specified datatypes

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an **ArrayList** with type **Long**,but i am trying to insert **int** value in it.I am **expecting int should also be stored in ArrayList** as int is smaller in size than long.

```
int i=1;
ArrayList<Long> obj=new ArrayList<Long>();
obj.add(i);//It is showing error that Storing int is not possible
```

Whereas the below one is possible

- List item

  ```
  long l=0;
  int i=5;
  l=i;
  ```

Please suggest the reason why ArrayList can't store lower value types.

Comment: Because autoboxing only boxes `long` to `Long` - it can't box `int` to `Long`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing this:

```
Long l = 0L;
int i = 5;
l=i;//Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Long
```

not this:

```
long l = 0;
int i = 5;
l = i;
```

It is not an ArrayList matter, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302605/how-do-i-convert-from-int-to-long-in-java) for details.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
ArrayList<Long> obj=new ArrayList<Long>();
```

is declaring that the list will store objects of *type* `Long`. It's storing references, and you can't put an `Integer` in, since an `Integer` **is-not** a `Long` (from the point of view of an object hierachy)

Don't think of the issue in term of numbers. Instead, try this. You have a list of `Cat`s. You can't store a `Dog` in there. But you could if the list was declared as a list of `Animals`.

You *could* declare the list to contain a `Number` (`Longs` and `Integers` are both `Number`s), but the fundamental issue is why are you mixing integers and longs in this collection ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to cast it to a long to make the above code work:

```
obj.add((long)i);
```

Because you specified that the ArrayList contains "Long", it forces all objects that go into it to be Long. And since ArrayList can be used to store any type of data, not just numbers, it doesn't have built-in mechanisms to convert ints to longs for example. Different rules apply.

Java primitives, like int and long, allow automatic conversion to comply with the way that C and C++ work, since Java was based on these languages originally. But it doesn't lead to the cleanest/safest code, and so some other more modern languages have removed even this type of fuziness.

Answer (score 0):

The `long` variable `l` also can't store lower value types. The assignment of `i` to `l` will implicitly do a [Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2), and the value is stored as a `long`.

When you try to insert an `int` value into a `List<Long>`, you're implicitly trying to do two conversions:

- Widening Primitive Conversion (`int` to `long`)
- [Boxing Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) (`long` to `Long`)

That double conversion will not be applied implicitly, so you have to tell the compiler to do it, by forcing the widening primitive conversion using a cast:

```
obj.add((long)i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `obj` to be a list of `Long` and thus it restricts you to use `add`

```
/**
 * Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
 *
 * @param e element to be appended to this list
 * @return <tt>true</tt> (as specified by {@link Collection#add})
 */
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
```

***Note*** - where `E` is from the class definition `ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>`

to primarily add only the type that your list should be consisting of. Hence changing the code as follows should work :

```
int i=1;
ArrayList<Long> obj=new ArrayList<Long>();
obj.add(Long.valueOf(i));
```

Also in your latter part the cast is taken care by the `=` operator as you assign it in following way :

```
l=i;
```

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList<Long>` can only store instances of `Long`.

You can "apparently" store `long`s in it, because the `long` is autoboxed to a `Long`:

```
list.add(someLong)
```

gets compiled to

```
list.add(Long.valueOf(someLong))
```

[Boxing conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) only applies from primitive to corresponding wrapper type: `long` to `Long`, `int` to `Integer` etc. It doesn't box an `int` to a `Long`, however. The compiler isn't *that* smart/lenient.

And Java doesn't widen an `Integer` to a `Long`, because widening isn't defined for those types: it's only defined for primitive numeric types.

You've just got to make the parameter a `long`, then it can autobox for you:

```
obj.add((long) i);
```

or, without autoboxing:

```
obj.add(Long.valueOf(i));
```

Note, in the latter case, `int` is an acceptable parameter for a method taking a `long` parameter because of widening conversion. Widening + autoboxing just isn't supported.