# How to transform int to long in Java?

Tags: java

Many convert string ip to long java code demo like this

```
private static int str2Ip(String ip)  {
    String[] ss = ip.split("\\.");
    int a, b, c, d;
    a = Integer.parseInt(ss[0]);
    b = Integer.parseInt(ss[1]);
    c = Integer.parseInt(ss[2]);
    d = Integer.parseInt(ss[3]);
    return (a << 24) | (b << 16) | (c << 8) | d;
}

private static long ip2long(String ip)  {
    return int2long(str2Ip(ip));
}

private static long int2long(int i) {
    long l = i & 0x7fffffffL;
    if (i < 0) {
        l |= 0x080000000L;
    }
    return l;
}
```

why we don't use other Java method instead method `int2long`? e.g.

```
Integer a = 0;
Long.valueof(a.toString());
```

Comment: *"why we don't use other Java method instend method int2long?"* Because that's really inefficient, creating a string to consume it as a number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert from int to Long in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302605/how-do-i-convert-from-int-to-long-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str2Ip` may return a negative `int` value. The `int2long` method you posted treats the input `int` as an unsigned `int` (though Java doesn't have unsigned `int`), and thus returns a positive `long`.

Converting the result of `str2Ip` directly to `Long` as you suggest (or simply casting the `int` to `long` or using `Number`'s `longValue()`) will convert negative `int`s to negative `long`s, which is a different behavior.

BTW, your `int2long` method can be simplified to:

```
private static long int2long(int i) {
    return i & 0xffffffffL;
}
```

For example, the output of the following:

```
System.out.println (ip2long("255.1.1.1"));
Integer a = str2Ip("255.1.1.1");
System.out.println (a.longValue ());
```

is

```
4278255873
-16711423
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Integer a = 0;
Long.valueof(a.toString());
```

is a fancy way of writing

```
long val = (long) myIntValue;
```

Problem is that a negative int value will remain negative if you do this kind of thing, the method int2long is converting a signed int to an unsigned long which is different from that.

Personally I think it would be simpler to initially work with `longs` instead of working on `ints`, i.e. something like this:

```
private static int str2Ip(String ip)  {
    return (int) ip2long;
}

private static long ip2long(String ip)  {
    String[] ss = ip.split("\\.");
    long a, b, c, d;
    a = Long.parseLong(ss[0]);
    b = Long.parseLong(ss[1]);
    c = Long.parseLong(ss[2]);
    d = Long.parseLong(ss[3]);
    return (a << 24) | (b << 16) | (c << 8) | d;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the longValue() method of the Number class. This means the method is available on any Number class child, including Integer. Note that this will not work with primitive types (e.g. int).

Answer (score 2):

and what about?

```
Integer a = 10;
return 1L * a;
```